# Passing Array to A Pre-Defined Javascript Function

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax

Pre-Defined Function:

```
Hopsys.prototype.multiple_new_lookups = function(symbol, units, hops, bounces, side, type, cb) {
  var params;
  params = {
    symbol: symbol,
    units: units,
    hops: hops,
    bounces: bounces,
    side: side,
    type: type
  };
  return this.make_request('hopsys/new/multi', params, cb);
};
```

This is the usage example the instructions give me:

```
Hopsys.multiple_new_lookups(symbol, units, hops, bounces, side, type, cb);
```

They also give an example cb function:

```
function(err, res, hop_id){
    console.log(hop_id);
}
```

so at least I know how to do the cb.

But I can't figure out how to create and send the array exactly as they want me to. I say array because how else can I pass multiple 'symbol' 'units' 'hops' 'bounces' 'side' and 'type'? The logic is that it can only give me multiple lookup results if I make multiple lookup requests. Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance for your time helping me out :)

Comment: If you are talking about an array for the parameters it would be easier as an object but a little more explanation of exactly what the end result should be would be helpful.

Comment: *"the array"* - What array are you talking about?

Comment: Which argument you want to pass as an array ? clarify please!

Comment: You're asking for help to a private API.  You should ask someone you work with for access to that documentation.  It won't be available on the net unless it has been hacked (doubtful), released by the company — I doubt since it's proprietary —, or someone has once worked there — I also doubt since it has 1-50 employees.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you can pass arrays as 'units', 'bounces' and 'hops' parameters. Maybe only 'units'.
Each parameter is a different variable, so you can not pass it an array of objects.

Comment: could you please include sample codes.It will be more better to understand

Comment: var units = ['foo','foo1','foo2','etc']; , then just pass it to a function as you did before - Hopsys.multiple_new_lookups(symbol, units, hops, bounces, side, type, cb);

Answer (score 0):

An example of how to pass arrays:

```
var symbols = ['some','acceptable','symbols'],
    units   = ['some','acceptable','units'],
    hops    = ['some','acceptable','hops'],
    bounces = ['some','acceptable','bounces'],
    sides   = ['some','acceptable','sides'],
    types   = ['some','acceptable','types'],
    cb      = function(){};


Hopsys.multiple_new_lookups(symbols, units, hops, bounces, sides, types, cb);
```